# How to convert numbers to time format in ruby

Tags: ruby

How would you write an expression that takes an integer argument of seconds and converts the value into a string?

so for example

```
to_time(3600) # => '1 hour(s) and 0 minute(s)'
```

I've found a lot of material on using the .time method however nothing I've found has been directly useful to what it is I'm trying to achieve. So far this is what my code looks like:

```
 def to_time(seconds)
  hours = (duration / 1.hour) % (1.day / 1.hour)
  minutes = (duration / 1.minute) % (1.hour / 1.minute)
   
   
   seconds.to_s.map{|h, m| seconds == "#{hours} hour(s) and #{minutes}(s)"}
end
```

Just to clarify my question, the expression takes an integer argument of seconds and converts the value into a string describing how many hours and minutes comprise that many seconds.

Comment: I'd use a gem, or something simple like https://gist.github.com/csanz/669588, which is what I found when I searched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear if what is exactly required, but if you need only hours, minutes you can have something like following

```
def to_time(seconds)
  return '0 hour(s) and 0 minute(s)' if seconds.to_i.zero?
  hours = seconds / 3600
  minutes = (seconds % 3600) / 60
  "#{hours} hour(s) and #{minutes} minute(s)"
end

to_time(3600) # 1 hour(s) and 0 minute(s)
to_time(3601) # 1 hour(s) and 0 minute(s)
to_time(3500) # 0 hour(s) and 58 minute(s)
to_time(323500) # 89 hour(s) and 51 minute(s)
to_time(0) # 0 hour(s) and 0 minute(s)
```

Edited: Removed `puts` from the method which Steve correctly mentioned in the comment. I have added that just for the testing.

Comment: I like this, it looks very clean and is very easy to read. I took out the seconds because the question only asks for hours and minutes. However it keeps returning nil:            
 ```Expected: "127 hour(s) and 36 minute(s)", instead got: nil``` this is the link to the kata: https://www.codewars.com/kata/5865cff66b5699883f0001aa/train/ruby

Comment: @KobadaTech You need to modify this code to meet the requirements of the kata. It's called a kata because it's practice, part of that practice is understanding the requirements of the kata.

Comment: Exactly, I just guide so that you can modify as per your requirement. btw `to_time(459360)` should return `127 hour(s) and 36 minute(s)`

Comment: The last line of the method is "puts" and "puts" returns nil.  Take out the "puts"  part of the last line and it should work.

Comment: ah my bad. Thank you @Salil

Answer (score 0):

```
def to_time(seconds)
  "%d hour(s) and %d minute(s)" % (seconds/60).divmod(60)
end
```

```
to_time(3600)   #=> "1 hour(s) and 0 minute(s)" 
to_time(3601)   #=> "1 hour(s) and 0 minute(s)" 
to_time(3500)   #=> "0 hour(s) and 58 minute(s)" 
to_time(323500) #=> "89 hour(s) and 51 minute(s)" 
to_time(0)      #=> "0 hour(s) and 0 minute(s)"
```

See [Integer#divmod](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-divmod).